# Homology groups of moduli of parabolic bundles with fixed determinant

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces, homology

I am looking for the **Homology groups of the moduli space of stable parabolic bundles over a smooth projective curve with fixed determinant**.

In particular, what is the second homology group of such moduli space?

Does anyone know of any references? Thanks a lot in advance.